# Time complexity of calculating the final digit sum of a number

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I want to calculate the time complexity of calculating the "final" digit sum of a number `n`: sum of the digits until I get A single digit number.

I know that in the first iteration an algorithm will perform `O(log n)` actions, in the second iteration it will be `O(log log n)` and so on, up until `log(log(...(log(n))...)) < 10`. Thus the number of iteration is `O(log* n)`, where `log* n` is the log-star value of `n`.

Is there a closed form for this sum?

Comment: What makes you "know that in the first iteration an algorithm will perform `O(log n)` actions"?

Comment: @ScottHunter The number `n` represented by `O(log n)` digits, and we need to sum all of them.

Comment: Are you trying to repeatedly sum digits until you are left with a single one, e.g. `99 -> 18 -> 9`? In this case the complexity should be `O(log n)` as the first iteration dominates the remaining ones.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I am not sure if I can claim that "the first iteration dominates the remaining ones" since the number of terms in the sum is a function of `n` as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This sum works out to Θ(log n). One way to see this is to notice that log n < n / 2 for all but tiny values of n, so we have that

> log n + log log n + log log log n + …
>
> ≤ log n + (log n) / 2 + (log n) / 4 + (log n) / 8 + …
>
> ≤ log n (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + …)
>
> = 2 log n
>
> = O(log n).

To see that the sum is Ω(log n), note that the first term itself is log n, so the sum is at least log n.